# How do I fix "emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'"

Tags: android, powershell, react-native, android-studio, cmd

So I currently have one AVD that I created with android studio for the Pixel 2 and I decided to create another one for the Pixel 3, which I named "react". After I tried opening "react" with the `emulator -react` command in the Power terminal, I received the following error:`emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'` At first I thought that the problem might be that I needed to add the location of this new emulator to the PATH in the control panel, but I already have a path titled: `C:\Users\Ahers\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator` so I don't think that's the issue. I'm not entirely sure what to do so any feedback would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

react is your avd name, so you can use this command to start it:

```sh
emulator -avd react
```

or

```sh
emulator @react
```